# Get field names from database result

Tags: php, mysql

Here I want to fetch the field names from the table name which is stored in the variable $table. And want to make a table headers of the field names. What's wrong with this approach I tried:

```
<?php

     $sql=mysql_query("show fields from $table");
     if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
     while($res = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
     {
     ?>
     <th><?php echo $res->field; ?></th>


     <?
      }
      else
      {
      echo "No data to display";
      }



        ?>
```

Comment: change $res->field; to $res->fields;

Comment: @JapanPro, no `field` is correct: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Comment: Please fix your question title. It does not describe the question at all.

Comment: Why do you think that something is wrong? What happens when you run this code? What debugging have you performed?

Comment: BTW, calling the result of `mysql_query(..)` `$sql` is misleading. The query that you give _to_ `mysql_query` is an SQL statement; the result that you get back from it is a database record resource and has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: @mario: I wanted the OP to learn to do it himself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah sorry ;P But I got a little annoyed by that too, so had to edit it. The actual problem is IMO that it's labeled `"Title"` and not `"Summary"`; so people don't bother to make it descriptive.

Comment: @mario: That's a good idea; I never thought of that. I doubt it'd make a big difference, though. If you're going to write "plz help with mai problem omg!!" in a `Title`, then you're going to do it in a `Summary` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query has to be

```
$sql=mysql_query("show columns from $table");
```

Comment: i had changed now..but stil no result when fetched :(

Comment: Do you want to display the table structure or the data of the table? If you want both, look at CodeCaster's answer!

Comment: I just wanna display the column names of the database table as a header of my html table

Comment: Remove your `if` and `else` and try again. There is a missing bracket after your `if`

Answer (score 2):

```
$printTHs = true;
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    if ($printTHs)
    {
        printTableHeader($res);
        $printTHs= false;
    }

    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($res as $val)
    {
        echo "<td>" . $val . "</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";

}

function printTableHeader($res)
{

    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($res as $col => $val)
    {
        echo "<th>" . $col . "</th>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: This would skip the first row from the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and then get the keys using `array_keys()`. This will return an array with all the keys.

Use `foreach()` to get your table headers

Answer (score 0):

Not the optimal solution, but would do it:

```
$results = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table);
if (mysql_num_rows($results))
{
    echo '<table>';
    $first = TRUE;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        if ($first = TRUE)
        {
            echo '<tr>';

            foreach ($row as $k => $v)
                echo '<th>' . $k . '</th>';

            echo '</tr>';
            $first = FALSE;
        }

        echo '<tr>';

        foreach ($row as $column)
            echo '<td>' . $column . '</td>';

        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```